# Must declare the scalar variable in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am developing an app in C# in which when I am interacting with my database SQL Server
 it is giving me the exception of 'Must declare the Scalar Variable'. The code is following

```
public DataTable Search(string clas)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        string query = "";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            if (clas != "")
            {
                query = "Select * from StudentManagement Where classEnrolled=@cls";
                //dataAdapter
                dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connectionString);
                dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("cls", clas));
            }

            dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connectionString);
            // Create a command builder to generate SQL update, insert, and
            // delete commands based on selectCommand. These are used to
            // update the database.
            SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

            // Populate a new data table and bind it to the BindingSource.
            table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            dataAdapter.Fill(table);
        }
        return table;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }    
}
```

Please help me

Comment: If you `indent` your code it becomes a lot easier to follow (for us, but also for yourself). This code does not look inviting to read, please edit it and fix indentation.

Comment: See here - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2010/03/03/must-declare-the-scalar-variable.aspx

Comment: If `clas != ""` evaluates to `false`, you are not adding the parameter at all, but it is still present in the query.

Comment: @hangy you are correct, but unused parameters aren't a problem, and it would have a different message if it was hitting this branch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a strong suspicion that `clas` is a  `null` reference. Note that this will still trigger your `!= ""` branch, since a null-reference is not the same as an empty string.

Maybe use:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(clas)) {...}
```

Instead?

A peculiarity of db-parameters is that they are not included if the .Value is `null`. Check the value you are sending in.

It doesn't apply in your case (since in normal SQL nothing ever equals NULL) but: if you *intend* to send NULL as a parameter, you must set the value to DBNull.Value instead.

Comment: Plus: if the `clas` parameter is indeed null or empty - the `query` string remains empty - not a valid SQL statement, either!